# How to add an object to vector array on stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am currently creating a program that will help me to learn new vocabulary. The workflow of the program is going to be ruled by the VocabularyTester class and it contains a list of objects of class WordPair stored in a vector array.

```
class VocabularyTester
{
private:
    std::vector<WordPair> wordList;
    std::vector<WordPair> failedPairs;
    std::vector<WordPair> passedPairs;
    WordPair recentPair;

public:
    VocabularyTester();
    void run();
    void loadWordList(std::wstring& vocabularyRaw);
    /*
     other parts of the code
    */
};

/* the function i'm having a problem with */
void VocabularyTester::loadWordList(std::wstring& vocabularyRaw)
{
    std::wstring rawPair;
    unsigned int iterator = 0, prevIterator = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        iterator = vocabularyRaw.find(L"\r\n", iterator);

        if (iterator == std::string::npos)
        {
            break;
        }

        rawPair = vocabularyRaw.substr(prevIterator, iterator);
        wordList.emplace_back(rawPair); /*there occurs the read access violation exception*/
        prevIterator = iterator;
    }
}
```

When the execution reaches wordList.emplace_back(rawPair), the read access violation exception is thrown, exactly here:

```
/* vector header file */
bool _Has_unused_capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // micro-optimization for capacity() != size()
        return (this->_Myend() != this->_Mylast());
        }
```

WordPair is a pair of 2 words, it has 2 string members: leftWord for a word in native language, rightWord for a word in language someone would like to learn. Here's the constructor of the object I am using to add it to the vector array:

```
WordPair::WordPair(std::wstring& rawPair)
{
    std::wstring separator = L" - ";
    size_t separatorPosition = rawPair.find(separator);
    std::wstring leftWord = rawPair.substr(0, separatorPosition);
    std::wstring rightWord = rawPair.substr(separatorPosition + separator.length());
    this->leftWord = leftWord;
    this->rightWord = rightWord;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `WordPair`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Where is the code for `_MyEnd()` and `_MyLast()`?

Comment: @Bigiansen That code is probably from inside the standard library implementation, and is really irrelevant. The problem is going to be in the code the OP written but haven't shown us.

Comment: I've added the explanation of the WordPair to the question.

Comment: Are you sure`separatorPosition` is not `npos` in `WordPair` constructor?

Comment: Did you verify the construction of the `WordPair` with a debugger?

Comment: yes, the class alone is being constructed properly, i've checked it. the problem occurs only when i try to add it to my vector array.

Comment: Just as a test, I suggest you do:
`WordPair wordpair(rawPair);`
`wordList.push_back(wordpair);`
you might get more meaningful errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did it that way previously and now again. Still, there's the same one exception, that's happening exactly when i try to add the object to the vector array. In the debugger I also see, that the WordPair object have been correctly created - string has been correctly splitted into the appropriate class members.

Comment: I think it's time for a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, it seems i have resolved it. The problem occurred, because the VocabularyTester object has been stored as a pointer in the Application class and it has not been initiated, therefore the VocabularyTester object has not been actually created. Now it makes sense, that such an exception has been thrown.